# Backup of user-defined entries of autocompletion in Texmaker?

Tags: texmaker, auto-completion

Where does Texmaker store the user-defined entries for the autocompletion feature? I'd like to back up (as well as export) my own entries...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: You can backup all of your settings via _Options->Settings File->Save a copy of the settings file_ and restore them with _Replace the settings file by a new one_ in the same menu, which I assume to include autocompletion, but I haven't tested it. Is that sufficient for your purposes? Edit: Yes, they are saved in the `.ini` backup file; in my test it was line 27, which starts with `Editor\UserCompletion=`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(*comment converted to answer*)

You can backup all of your settings via *Options→Settings File→Save a copy of the settings file* and restore them with *Replace the settings file by a new one* in the same menu.

[image: screenshot]

The .ini file you get as a backup contains the custom autocomplete entries; in my file, it was line 27:

```
Editor\UserCompletion=\\ex, \\documentclass{\x2022}, \\addfontfeatures{\x2022}, \\makeatletter, \\makeatother, \\newfontfamily\x2022{\x2022}, \\newfontfamily\x2022[\x2022]{\x2022}, \\tiny, \\scriptsize, \\footnotesize, \\small, \\normalsize, \\large, \\Large, \\LARGE, \\huge, \\Huge, \\toprule, \\midrule, \\bottomrule, \\begingroup, \\endgroup, \\parbox{\x2022}{\x2022}
```