# Texmaker - autocomplete problem

Tags: texmaker, auto-completion

Is there a way to stop Texmaker from auto-putting the completion tag of every command when I use autocomplete? Like `\begin{document}` and I press enter in the auto-complete and it includes the `\end{document}`. Is there a way to switch this off without switching off auto-complete?

Comment: for what it's worth: former versions of texmaker used to put only the \begin-tags with auto-complete  (or the \end-tag, where applicable)

Comment: @longtom yeah, that totally makes sense. It should've been like that. Could you tell me which version?

Comment: i think that was somewhere around version 2.0...  (that's way back)

Answer (score 3):

I think that is not possible without touching the source code. You can customize completions in in `User > Customize Completion` as explained in [Customize auto-completion in Texmaker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88726/customize-auto-completion-in-texmaker). However even any custom completion with `\begin{...}` is ended automatically with `\end{...}` and very unfortunately you cannot modify the items provided by TeXmaker.

I figured that a modification of the file settings could do to the trick, but I failed completely in this sense. As explained in 
[Backup of user-defined entries of autocompletion in Texmaker?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81858/backup-of-user-defined-entries-of-autocompletion-in-texmaker)
you can save a setting file, modify the fields of `Editor\UserCompletion` or `Shortcuts\data` where the are defined shorcuts as `\\begin{quote}\n/\n\\end{quote}/0/1` and restore it, but this has no effect on the default autocompletion, as well as modifying directly the hidden configuration file  `~\.config/xm1/texmaker.ini` ... so this a dead end for me. :-(

Comment: So there's no way to do this, then?

Comment: As far as I know, no, but probably  will be better answers.

Comment: it's been a requested feature to auto-add the \end-tag...  i think it's indeed no longer possible without altering the source code

Comment: @longtom , you mean it was requested as a feature? Older editions don't have this then, right?

Comment: @SPRajagopal, as i mentioned before, my memory says something like: "long, long, loong time ago, texmaker didn't auto-add the \end-tag"...  I also found evidence in the update log at the texmaker site...  but it seems to have been that way in versions prior to 2.0...  I don't think it's worth going so far back...